# Finding the convolution of two histograms

Tags: statistics, numpy, probability, histogram, convolution

The probability distribution of the sum of two random variables, x and y, is given by the convolution of the individual distributions. I'm having some trouble doing this numerically. In the following example, x and y are uniformly distributed, with their respective distributions approximated as histograms. My reasoning says that the histograms should be convoluted to give the distribution of, x+y.

```
from numpy.random import uniform
from numpy import ceil,convolve,histogram,sqrt
from pylab import hist,plot,show

n = 10**2

x,y = uniform(-0.5,0.5,n),uniform(-0.5,0.5,n)

bins = ceil(sqrt(n))

pdf_x = histogram(x,bins=bins,normed=True)
pdf_y = histogram(y,bins=bins,normed=True)

s = convolve(pdf_x[0],pdf_y[0])

plot(s)
show()
```

which gives the following,

[image]

In other words, a triangular distribution, as expected. However, I have no idea how to find the x-values. I would appreciate it if someone could correct me here.

Comment: How would the `x`-values be correct if you didn't even specify them in the plot? Also, strictly speaking, `histogram` wont give you a `pdf` so simply way. But please first consider the number of your `bins` respect to `n`. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In order to still move on (towards more murky details), I further adapted your code like this:

```
from numpy.random import uniform
from numpy import convolve, cumsum, histogram, linspace

s, e, n= -0.5, 0.5, 1e3
x, y, bins= uniform(s, e, n), uniform(s, e, n), linspace(s, e, n** .75)
pdf_x= histogram(x, normed= True, bins= bins)[0]
pdf_y= histogram(y, normed= True, bins= bins)[0]
c= convolve(pdf_x, pdf_y); c= c/ c.sum()
bins= linspace(2* s, 2* e, len(c))
# a simulation
xpy= uniform(s, e, 10* n)+ uniform(s, e, 10* n)
c2= histogram(xpy, normed= True, bins= bins)[0]; c2= c2/ c2.sum()

from pylab import grid, plot, show, subplot
subplot(211), plot(bins, c)
plot(linspace(xpy.min(), xpy.max(), len(c2)), c2, 'r'), grid(True)
subplot(212), plot(bins, cumsum(c)), grid(True), show()
```

Thus, giving plots something like this:
[image]
Where the upper part represents the `PDF` (blue line), which indeed looks quite triangular  and the simulation (red dots), which reflects the triangular shape. Lower part represents the `CDF`, which also looks to follow nicely the expected `S`-curve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Going according to the Wikipedia article on [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), I would expect the new x range to run from -1 to 1. That's the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: This (pdf_x= histogram(x)**[0]**) ignores the bin "locations" for the histograms, converting the histogram into a pdf, before convolution. So for real data, make sure your two data set histograms are "aligned" to have exactly the same bins (using that `bins=bins` argument) before doing this. You'd fill any nonoverlapping gaps or margins with zero counts (empty bins). Otherwise the resulting PDF (and CDF) will be wrong even though they look like S curves and triangles.